# Height size change is not causing state update React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to have my Carousel height resize dynamically upon change. However I can't seem trigger a state change purely from a childs height change.

Listening to children was pretty good, infact I'm not fully sure why it's not working.

The problem occurs when an error message is appended to a child within the carousel. It doesn't update.

Currently the best thing I know of to do is an interval...
Is there a better way?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import './Carousel.scss';

// Wrapped children components must be placed inside of <div> elements
const Carousel = ({slideTo, children}) => {

  const [carouselStyle, setCarouselStyle] = useState({});
  const activeRef = useRef(null);
  const index = slideTo - 1

  const newChildren = [];
  children.map((d,i) => {
    let addClass = (d.props.className !== undefined) ? d.props.className: ""
    const newProps = { 
      key: i 
    };

    if(i === index){
      addClass += " active"
      newProps.ref = activeRef;
    }

    newProps.className = addClass.trim();

    const newChild = React.cloneElement(d, newProps);

    newChildren.push(newChild);
    return false
  });

  const carouselContainerStyle = {
    left: (((slideTo * 100) - 100) * -1) + "%",
    width: (newChildren.length * 100)+ "%"
  }



  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("int");

      if(activeRef != null){
        if(carouselStyle.height === undefined || carouselStyle.height !== activeRef.current.clientHeight){
          setCarouselStyle({
            height: activeRef.current.clientHeight,
          });
        }
      }

    },50)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("children update");

    if(activeRef.current !== null){
      setCarouselStyle({
        height: activeRef.current.clientHeight,
      });
    }
  },[slideTo,children]);


  return (
    <div className="carousel" style={carouselStyle}>
      <div style={carouselContainerStyle} className="carousel-container">
        {newChildren}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Implementation

```
<Carousel slideTo={slide}>
 <div><SignIn/></div>
 <div><SignUp/></div>
</Carousel>
```

Comment: Please make a **minimal** producible example, also why you mapping `children` when its a react component? (you should use children API)

Comment: Also, I'm sure that putting `children` as dep array won't work because the reference won't change.

Comment: @DennisVash I need to add a ref and class to the active child. I can't change them directly so I'm cloning them. Just cloning them all since it's less headache/error prone.

Comment: Cloning them like so is error prone...